# Object with very strange behavior inside component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an object who is behaving very strangely. I don't know what's going on.

my code:

```js
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    const { listingId } = $page.params
    import { db } from '../../../../firebase.config'
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation'
    import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'
    import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
    import { scale } from 'svelte/transition'
    import LeafletMap from '$lib/LeafletMap.svelte'

    let listing = {}
    
    const auth = getAuth()

    const fetchListing = async () => {
        const docRef = doc(db, 'listings', listingId)
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

        if (docSnap.exists) {
            listing = docSnap.data()
        }

        console.log('listing', listing)
    }
    fetchListing()

    // call listing
    listing
</script>

<main in:scale>
    
    <div class="listingDetails">
        <p class="listingName">
            {listing.name} - ${listing.offer ? listing.discountedPrice : listing.regularPrice}
        </p>
        <p class="listingLocation">
            {listing.location}
        </p>
        <p class="listingType">
            Para {listing.type === 'rent' ? 'Alugar' : 'Vender'}
        </p>
        {#if listing.offer}
            <p class="discoutPrice">
                ${listing.regularPrice - listing.discountedPrice}
                de desconto
            </p>
        {/if}
        <ul class="listingDetailsList">
            <li>
                {#if listing.bedrooms > 1}
                    {listing.bedrooms} quartos
                {/if}
                {#if listing.bedrooms === 1}
                    {listing.bedrooms} quarto
                {/if}
            </li>
            <li>
                {#if listing.bathrooms > 1}
                    {listing.bathrooms} banheiros
                {/if}
                {#if listing.bathrooms === 1}
                    {listing.bathrooms} banheiro
                {/if}
            </li>
            <li>
                {#if listing.parking == true}
                    estacionamento
                {:else}
                    sem estacionamento
                {/if}
            </li>
            <li>
                {#if listing.furnished == true}
                    mobiliado
                {:else}
                    não mobiliado
                {/if}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="listingLocationTitle">Localização</p>

        <LeafletMap lat={'26.2137376'} lng={'-80.2094237'} zoom={15} />

        {#if auth.currentUser?.uid == listing.user}
            <a href={`/contact/${listing.user}?listingName=${listing.name}`} class="primaryButton">
                Entre em contato com o proprietário
            </a>
        {/if}
    </div>
</main>
```

My `console.log('listing', listing)` inside the function `fetchListing` calls the list:

[image]

But if I try to do the same, outside of the function I get this:

[image]

It's funny because works but I need to acess `listing.geolocation.lat` and `listing.geolocation.lng` inside the component `<LeafletMap/>`. If I put this `{listing.geolocation.lat.toString()}` outside the component I get the number. But if I do this:

```
<LeafletMap lat={listing.geolocation.lat.toString()} lng={'-80.2094237'} zoom={15} />
```

I get this `error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')`

My `<LeafletMap/>` component:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import { browser } from '$app/env'
    export let lat
    export let lng

    onMount(async () => {
        if (browser) {
            const leaflet = await import('leaflet')

            const map = leaflet.map('map').setView([lat, lng], 13)

            leaflet
                .tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution:
                        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                })
                .addTo(map)

            leaflet.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map)
        }
    })
</script>

<main>
    <div id="map" />
</main>

<style>
    @import 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css';
    main #map {
        height: 800px;
    }
</style>
```

If I do this: `<LeafletMap lat={'42.233283'} lng={'-80.2094237'} zoom={15} />` I get the perfect location, so, my component is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchListing` is an async function and therefore `listing` might not be set when the `LeafletMap` is rendered.

My recommendation is to add/update the marker once the latitude and longitude is set as shown in the example below. This also allows you to update the marker during runtime and can easily be extendet for multiple markers.

```
<script>    
    export let lat;
    export let lng;

    let map;
    let mounted = false;
    $: if (mounted && lat && lng) updateMarkers(lat, lng);

    async function updateMarkers(latitude, longitude) {      
      const leaflet = await import('leaflet');
      leaflet.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);
      map.setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
    }

    async function createMap(container) {
      const leaflet = await import('leaflet');
      map = leaflet.map(container);
      leaflet
        .tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
        .addTo(map);
      return map;
    }

    function mapAction(container) {
      createMap(container).then(function(map){
        mounted = true;
        return {
          destroy: () => {
            map.remove();
          }
        };
      });          
    }
</script>

<div style={$$props.style} use:mapAction />

<style>
  @import 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css';
  div {
      height: 800px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, miwin! Works perfetcly. :)